# jQuery was auto loaded in my Zend Framework application

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I have a Zend Framework application. It works normal and load Jquery from my local folder. But after try [this tutorial](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/) (but removed the Jquery call as in the tut) and revised some JS call (load some JS file from layout instead of view), it work abnomally: automatically load Jquery from Google CDN:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I try to find in my code the function of calling Jquery from above address but can't find (and I remember that I don't put any thing like this.
Can you let me know how and in what case, the Zend Framework will automatically call the Jquery from Google CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found the problem: I used:

```
echo $this->jQuery();
```

as I see the instruction somewhere 
In stead, I replaced with:

```
echo $this->jQuery()->setLocalPath($this->baseUrl().'/js/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js');
```

And it worked